# Ignoring octalescape characters in a string

Tags: java, string

Here is a sample String "one/two/three\123today" that i get from an unknown source i.e i cannot change the format of the input string that i get.
I need to get the sub-string after the backslash i.e 123today

Here the \123 is being considered as an octal escape.
I tried splitting it as a character sequence, but this considers the octal escape as a character.

I am writing the code in java.
How do i go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is very simple.

If you want your Java program to contain *a Java String literal* containing the character sequence '\', '1', '2', '3', you *MUST* write it as `"...\\123..."` in your source code.

For example:

```
String testInput = "one/two/three\\123today";
int pos = test.indexOf("\\123");
```

However, backslash escaping is *only* relevant to Java string (or character) *literals* in your *source code*.  If your program reads the String from some file (for example), or if it assembles the String in some way that doesn't involve String or character literals, no escaping is required in the source file, or whatever.  For example:

```
char backslash = (char) 92;
String testInput = "one/two/three" + backslash + "123today";
int pos = test.indexOf(backslash + "123");
```

or

```
String input = ... // read a file that contains the sequence '\', '1', '2', '3'
int pos = test.indexOf("\\123"); // search for that sequence
```

(Aside: some programming languages provide alternative String literal syntaxes that mean that you can dispense with escaping.  Java does not.  End of story.)

> Here the \2 is being considered as an octal escape by eclipse.

For the record, it the Java Language Specification that defines this.  Eclipse is just (correctly) implementing the Java Language Specification.

Answer (score 1):

The string `"one/two/three\123today"` is exactly the same as `"one/two/threeStoday"`. If you want to split on an `'S'` character, you can do that, but there’s no way to tell whether a character was encoded directly or via an escape sequence.

Comment: How do i replace \1 with \\1?, replace doesn't work, neither does converting it to an character array.

Comment: You change the string literal in your source file. If I’m reading the question correctly, the problem that the string contains a `'\123'` character is one of syntax.

Comment: Yes i have tried that out. The string '\\' cannot be found as '\1' is being considered as an entity.

Comment: @Vivek: How can that be possible when the `\ ` before the `1` is already being escaped?

Comment: yes that is the problem, how do i prevent it from being escaped?

Comment: @jleedev: I am getting this string from an unknown source. Is there no way i can make changes to this string to get the output i desire i.e to get the string 123today?

Comment: @Vivek That’s a pretty bad situation to be in.

Comment: @Vivek: actually, that is not the problem; read my answer carefully.