# Java - Evaluate String from String

Tags: java, string, eval

in my Java code I have this snippet:

```
String str = "\\u9601";
```

But I want it to be:

```
String str = "\u9601";
```

which represents a wide character.

Are there ways to do this?

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

**Supplementary:**

Sorry for the badly-described question.

```
System.out.print("\u9601"); //this will display a Chinese character
```

I am currently request a webpage(URL) which response with a JSON.
If dumped to Console using "System.out.print", the JSON will turn out to be 6 visible characters  **\**, **u**, **9**, **6**, **0** and **1**,but not a Chinese character in eclipse.

So actually what I want is are there APIs can convert "\\u9601" to "\u9601", since I can not hard code the Java source for the contents comes from website.

Comment: You could delete one of the backslashes.

Comment: No, it doesn’t represent a “wide character”.  It represents an abtract Unicode code point, U+9601.  It is no wider than a LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A. Abstract code points have no width.

Comment: I must be missing something, because if you wanted to use a [unicode character escape](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html#100850) you could delete a '\' from `str`.

Comment: Well, that, or just replace "\\u" with "\u".

Comment: @tchrist: I think he meant "wide" as in "double-byte".  (Obviously, all string characters in Java are two bytes, so I think he really meant "non-ASCII.")

Comment: Eerily similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094288/ignoring-octalescape-characters-in-a-string/4094294#4094294

Comment: @cdhowie: I have a feeling that @tchrist knew that and was just try to make the point that "wide" has fallen into disuse in this context

Comment: @Adrian: Yes, that's exactly correct.

Comment: @cdhowie: I wouldn't say all string *characters* in Java are two bytes.  I would say `char` units are, because these are UTF-16 elements—and thus sometimes half-elements — but that logical characters sometimes require two such 16-bit code units due to the unpleasant business of surrogates. **UTF-16 is a variable-width encoding, like UTF-8.** Fortunately the regex engine allow and indeed requires you to deal with **logical** characters.  `"\u0061"`, `"\u00DF"`,  `"\u03C3"`, and `"\uD83D\uDCA9"` all test true when matched against the pattern that says there is just one character there: `"^.$"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want it to be `String str = "\u9601";`, keep it that way!

**Edit based on the updated question**

The [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava%28java.lang.String%29) method in the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi) API should be of help:

```
    String str = "\\u9601";
    str = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(str);
    System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Sorry I can hard code the source, what I supplied is just an sample.

Comment: Indeed, the contents of the String variable is read from a website.

Comment: Hi have the same problem but for ASCII characters, String str = "\\026" to String str = "\026"