# How to apply the escape characters in java string

Tags: java, string, escaping, eval

My problem is
I read a text from a file
In the text file there is some text like that

```
Base64.valueOf("\030)?8*\"q1;16=\0331:?5/8~:8(6y", 42 - -33))
```

I able to get the text using regular expression

```
\030)?8*\"q1;16=\0331:?5/8~:8(6y
```

but the String is equal below statement

```
regText = "\\030)?8*\\"q1;16=\\0331:?5/8~:8(6y"
```

But the exact string I want is

```
expectedText = "\030)?8*\"q1;16=\0331:?5/8~:8(6y"
```

So how can I turn the regText to expectedText

In [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290028/java-evaluate-string-from-string) it do almost what I expected

Except it is not turn the "\030" to "\030" instead it turn to "030"

Comment: What is the text file meant to represent?

Comment: This will not compile - Base64.valueOf("\030)?8*\"q1;16=\0331:?5/8~:8(6y", 42 - -33)). regText is not escaped correctly either. Can you elaborate on your question a little ?

Comment: @Jon It is a source file with decrypt. I try to read it in another problem and recalculate it value Base64.valueOf("\030)?8*\"q1;16=\0331:?5/8~:8(6y", 42 - -33))

Comment: @YuanChen: What do you mean by "with decrypt"? I suspect that any simplistic attempt to parse a source file will be very brittle.

Comment: @DeepakBala I will import the Base64 class at my program and then I need to get the text to re calculate the value, Base64.valueOf(expectedText, 9). But the problem is when I read the source file it already escape the character. for example when you use String text = "\n" then the text when output is a new line but when I read from text file the text = "\\n" so when ouput it is \n not a new line. So I can't recalculate the value.

Comment: @YuanChen So the question is - 'How do you escape all string characters properly ?' (like \n \t \\)

Comment: @DeepakBala Yes, but also the "\\026" to "\026" check here. This is almost what I expected http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290028/java-evaluate-string-from-string except it turn "\\026" to "026"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem becomes easier if the program writing to the file writes the data properly to begin with. If that is not possible use the StringEscapeUtils from apache commons lang.

```
System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("New line: \\n Tab: \\t"));
```

That call manually processes \n and converts it to a newline. It only handles literals. You are on your own for octals and [other escapes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6). You can always fork the code and work on the octals too.

Comment: Hi, Thank. I have added the Map for octal string to replace it. Look like everything work now. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By using [String#replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) you can do the following :

```
expectedText = regText.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\");
```

Which will replace the double backslashes in the `regText` string, to the simple backslashes that you expect.

Comment: Hi my problem is I need to get replace some escape characters In the read string. line the "\\030" need to be "\030"